# Using if else syntax in field calculator with Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, syntax

I want to calculate a field in the field calculator that are dependent on the values in 4 other columns.

My columns are "A", "B", "C" and "D"

Now I want to fill the column "X" with:

if "A" and "B" are equal "0" I want to do "calculation_1_(A,B,C,D)"

if only "A" equals "0" I want to do "calculation_2_(A,B,C,D)"

if only "B" equals "0" I want to do "calculation 3_(A,B,C,D)"

else I want to do "calculation_4_(A,B,C,D)"

Can somebody give me the code for this? I am struggling with syntax and if/else structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of code in field calculator / calculate field:

Field Name: X

Expression: `calc1(!A!,!B!,!C!,!D!)`

Expression type: PYTHON_9.3

Code Block(/Pre-Logic Script Code):

```
def calc1(a,b,c,d):
  if a==0 and b==0:
    return a+b+c+d+1+2+3+4
  elif a==0 and b<>0:
    return a-b-c-d
  else:
    return a+b-c+d
```

Answer (score 4):

This python function implements the logic you described in your question:

```
def calculate_X(A,B,C,D):
    if A == 0 and B == 0:
        X = calculation_1(A,B,C,D)

    elif A == 0 and B != 0 and C != 0 and D != 0:
        X = calculation_2(A,B,C,D)

    elif B == 0 and A != 0 and C != 0 and D != 0:
        X = calculation_3(A,B,C,D)

    else:
        X = calculation_4(A,B,C,D)

    return X
```

Then access the function using the expression

```
calculate_X(!A!, !B!, !C!, !D!)
```

---

It is a little unclear based on the question whether the values of "C" and "D" should be tested for calculations 2 and 3 (since they are not tested for calculation 1). If "C" and "D" should not be tested, then just use `A == 0 and B != 0` instead of `A == 0 and B != 0 and C != 0 and D != 0`

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check "Code Block":

```
def calc_X(A,B,C,D):
    if A == 0 and B == 0:
       return calculation_1(A,B,C,D)

    elif A == 0 and B != 0:
       return calculation_2(A,B,C,D)

    elif B == 0 and A != 0:
        return calculation_3(A,B,C,D)

    else:
        return calculation_4(A,B,C,D)
```

Then:
`X = calc_X(!A!, !B!, !C!, !D!)`